# MessageBus.callbackInterval does not work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, message-bus

I've been using the [message_bus gem](https://github.com/SamSaffron/message_bus) for a few months as a more simplified alternative to a websocket solution. The default `MessageBus.callbackInterval`is too wide, so I want to narrow it. I've done this successfully in my development env. However, when deploying to production it seems that the second line below is ignored:

```
MessageBus.start();
MessageBus.callbackInterval = 1800; # this should change the interval frequency, but it doesn't
MessageBus.subscribe("/some_id", function(status) {
  // work
});
```

Any idea how I could debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't personally encountered this problem before, but like with many JavaScript libraries/files in Rails it is probably something in the assets pipeline.

Are you certain that you included JavaScript required for message bus to work in your view with:

```
<script src="message-bus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in assets

```
//= require message-bus
```

If you're using a Ruby version of this gem, you can always try to set this using Ruby instead of JavaScript.

```
client = MessageBus::Client.new('http://127.0.0.1/8000') #port is optional
#you should be able to do 
client.callbackInterval = 1800
#after that you should be able to do 


client.subscribe('/message') do |payload|
  # Do stuff
end
```

For more info refer to https://github.com/lowjoel/message_bus-client